# Heroku doesnt precompile assets for rails4

Tags: ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

The documentation here says that heroku with pre-compile assets during deployement in Rails4.

However , 
I dont see the precompile assets message.

```
     Using thin (1.6.1)
       Using twitter-bootstrap-rails (2.2.8)
       Using uglifier (2.3.1)
       Using will_paginate (3.0.4)
       Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Bundle completed (1.37s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
       Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for Ruby  -> console, rake, web, worker
```

I am facing issues with bootstrap in my app, where the nav bar wont load properly + some other nuances and I think its the asset precompile issue.

I am using Rails4, Ruby2.0

I have assets enabled in application.rb

```
config.assets.enabled = true
```

Precompiling manually did not help

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deleting the public/assets folder helped. Also I ran heroku run rake assets:clean.

```
After that I could see:
----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
```

The navbar loads fine now !

Answer (score 20):

Had this same problem. I had precompiled locally for some reason and then pushed to Heroku.

Saw Heroku give the line "Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally" which made me realize it wasn't precompiling all the things.

When I did a "git add ." and committed, I saw that it was adding a bunch of public files. Pushing that to Heroku got it to work. So I had to precompile and git add everytime, basically doing Heroku's work for it and making a mess in my public folder. It got the job done, but was a poor fix.

I looked for the "manifest" that heroku mentioned and eventually found a ".sprockets-manifest..." file in the public directory.

Deleted that and Heroku was once again my friend.

Found this question as part of my research so I thought I'd share what I found in case anyone else sees this, or has any elaborational thoughts.

Now I have to go and see if .sprockets-manifest was important to anything else ....

Comment: saved my life here. did not realise this was even pushed to the repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with the asset pipeline for a while. There seems to be a bit of confusion as to how the asset pipeline works among newer Rubyists. In my experience, this is my workflow to the asset pipeline for Heroku.

- Make sure that assets work locally on localhost (required for Heroku)
- Delete the public/assets folder in the Rails directory with `rm -rf ./public/assets`
- Make a new assets directory with `mkdir public/assets`
- Run the `rake assets:precompile` command
- You should see a list of assets being precompiled in your command line
- Once assets are precompiled, you should commit the changes via the following commands: `git add -A` then `git commit -am "commit message goes here"`
- Finally, push to heroku via `git push heroku master`

NOTE: This bears repeating -- make sure your assets work normally on localhost before pushing to Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

The message `Detected manifest file, assuming assets were compiled locally` is shown if there is `.sprockets-manifest-*.json` or `manifest-*.json` in public assets. So either removing individual file or whole `public/assets` works.

The source code for buildpack is [here](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/blob/master/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb)