# Chartkick works on localhost but displays "loading" on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-visualization, chartkick

I'm just playing with chartkick using data I entered directly into the view. I'm using the Google Charts API option for the display. When I open my index page on my localhost, everything displays perfectly, but I am stuck in loading on heroku. Does Google Charts not work with heroku? Am I doing something else wrong slowing down the process?

Here is the [file](https://github.com/harrisongill/ReadingInterestInventory2014/blob/master/app/views/chartdisplay/index.html.erb) in question and how it looks on [heroku](http://rii14.mrgill.org).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Chartkick is not defined (index):22(anonymous function) (index):22
```

If you have any problems with javascript, always check javascript console (available i.e. in chrome).

This particular error indicates that chartkick is not loaded. If you look at developer tools in chrome under "Network tab", you will see that assets are not loaded. You can fix this by following heroku guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline

Comment: This helped me to solve this problem. My assets were not being compiled on Heroku because I had a sprockets.manifest file that was telling the build process that assets were being compiled locally. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/31842364/2232797